# Cannot grep a file from one line number to another in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am unable to grep a file from a shell script written. Below is the code

```
#!/bin/bash

startline6=`cat /root/storelinenumber/linestitch6.txt`
endline6="$(wc -l < /mnt/logs/arcfilechunk-aim-stitch6.log.2017-11-08)"
awk 'NR>=$startline6 && NR<=$endline6' /mnt/logs/arcfilechunk-aim-stitch6.log.2017-11-08 | grep -C 100 'Error in downloading indivisual chunk' > /root/storelinenumber/error2.txt
```

The awk command is working on standalone basis though when the start and end line numbers are given manually.

Comment: What's is happening instead? Have you tried just passing either the start or the end line number manually, and using the above to determine the other one? Can you narrow it down to either the start or the end not working?

Comment: Like manually running the command below

awk 'NR>=0 && NR<=1000' /mnt/logs/arcfilechunk-aim-stitch6.log.2017-11-08 | grep -C 100 'Error in downloading indivisual chunk' > /root/storelinenumber/error2.txt

I am getting output as I have expected. But the shell script where I have dynamically passed the start and end point, I am not getting any output to the error2.txt file

Comment: Right, but why is that? If you don't pipe into grep, are you getting no output? The wrong lines? Does `echo $startline6` and `echo $endline6` give you the output you expect?

Comment: Yes I am getting startline and endline properly printed with the correct value when I am doing echo.

Comment: Answering the rest of my questions would be useful too. Another thing to consider is do `$startline6` and `$endline6` end with a newline? Could that be your problem?

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with the syntax. The last line was modified to

```
awk 'NR>='"$startline9"' && NR<='"$endline9"'' /mnt/logs/arcfilechunk-aim-stitch9.log | grep -C 100 'Error in downloading indivisual chunk' >> /root/storelinenumber/error.txt
```

It solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have your attempted variable expansions within single quotes, meaning that they won't actually *be* expanded.

When passing shell variables into `awk`, I prefer them to be actual first-class `awk` variables so I don't have to worry about that sort of stuff:

```
awk -vstl=$startline6 -vendl=$endline6 'NR>=stl && NR<=endl ...
```